# how to use facet_wrap with map

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a spatial data frame created after reading shapefile ( after fortify etc.) 
lets say the dataframe name is state_shp

head(state_shp) looks as follows

```
      long      lat order  hole piece id group State_Name
64727 76.85065 30.87512 64727 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
64728 76.86594 30.86691 64728 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
64729 76.87530 30.86977 64729 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
64730 76.88317 30.87437 64730 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
64731 76.89213 30.88219 64731 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
64732 76.90011 30.88449 64732 FALSE     1 10  10.1    Haryana
143451 81.37566 28.16789 143451 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143452 81.37801 28.17139 143452 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143453 81.38133 28.17313 143453 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143454 81.39057 28.17307 143454 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143455 81.39486 28.17392 143455 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143456 81.41698 28.17376 143456 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143457 81.42917 28.17103 143457 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143458 81.43936 28.16479 143458 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143459 81.44362 28.16037 143459 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143460 81.45018 28.15650 143460 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
143461 81.45144 28.14945 143461 FALSE     1 31  31.1 Uttar Pradesh
```

It has many more rows, now when I am using following code

```
  ggplot()+geom_path(data=state_shp,aes(state_shp$long,state_shp$lat,
                          group=state_shp$group),color="black")+
  facet_wrap(.~State_Name)
```

I am getting this as out put which is wrong. I don't know where is the mistake

[image]

Comment: What do you expect, how would your desired output look like? 
Further could you maybe provide a little bit more date (e.g. for 2 states), to make this more reproducible?

Comment: These plots are wrong for eg. under heading West Bengal Gujarat plot has come, Uttar Pradesh, Haryana, West Bengal and Karnataka has gone in under Gujarat heading. and updated the data

Comment: Try to use ggplot without the `state_shp$`: `ggplot() + geom_path(data=state_shp,aes(long, lat, group=group),color="black") +  facet_wrap(.~State_Name)` It already knows where to look for the variables with the `data==state_shp` argument

Comment: Thanks a lot Kath,  it worked